# CSS grid template for Webapplication with big datatable

Tags: css, layout, grid, html

For the project I have the following Layout: 
[image: Layout Web application with big data table]

The content of the page should use the entire space on the screen since the table will be very big. I think a responsive layout is the right for that.

The header contains two Logos which float to the left and a Login block floating to the right side.

In the content area the Navigation box will be always on the left side. Next to it is the table. In the table rows and columns can be added, that is why the table can get very big and should use all the available space. At some point a horizontal slider makes it possible to scroll the table left and right.

Under the content the fototer contains four boxes with additional Information.

What is the best grid solution to realize this kind of Web application?